# Regex not working with web crawler

Tags: php, regex, web, web-crawler

I have this simple web crawler that returns all links ( tags) from the Google search result page, however, my preg_match function doesn't seem to be returning the relevant links I want that are in between 2 strings. I believe my regex is correct though, I've tested it on several other platforms.

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) { 

preg_match_all("/url\?q=(.*?)&sa=U&ei=/", $element->href, $matches); //attempt to retrieve the      actual link in between these strings

echo  $element->href.'<br/>'; //prints out each of the links 

}

print_r($matches);
```

Here is what the page which I am trying to retrieve the relevant links from looks like when Im searching for someone named John Smith

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww
https://www.google.com/search?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl
https://play.google.com/?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=w8
https://www.youtube.com/results?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=w1
https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/
https://www.google.com/calendar?tab=wc
https://translate.google.com/?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wT
http://www.google.com/mobile/?hl=en&tab=wD
https://www.google.com/search?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp
https://wallet.google.com/manage/?tab=wa
https://www.google.com/search?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=shop&source=og&sa=N&tab=wf
https://www.blogger.com/?tab=wj
https://www.google.com/finance?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=we
https://plus.google.com/photos?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wq
https://www.google.com/search?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=vid&source=og&sa=N&tab=wv
http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3DJohn%2BSmith
http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en
/preferences?hl=en
http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en
/webhp?hl=en
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CAUQ_AU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CAYQ_AU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CAcQ_AU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CAgQ_AU
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=John+Smith&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CAkQ_AU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CAoQ_AU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:h&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CA8QpwU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:d&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CA8QpwU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:w&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CA8QpwU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:m&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CA8QpwU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CA8QpwU
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&source=lnt&tbs=li:1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CA8QpwU
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFgBV3CPR5ydtty6z72kDKto_Ij7A
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:2n5isO4EbUAJ:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CBcQIDAA&usg=AFQjCNGxUvb-aHUJmV-p4VbGXmUJE1nPBw
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CBgQHzAA
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)%23Early_adventures&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CBoQ0gIoADAA&usg=AFQjCNFK7RzMUfQA5LZYUNaL2C_K0cEbjA
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)%23In_Jamestown&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CBsQ0gIoATAA&usg=AFQjCNF0pFVxwtdohofHr3bWQXJhk1XMcA
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)%23New_England&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CBwQ0gIoAjAA&usg=AFQjCNE4VqtjkQwsNzO_haCNSUi-3bgTsw
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)%23Death_and_burial&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CB0Q0gIoAzAA&usg=AFQjCNFAr4O8yWEK93_GyyN6_srpqLaljQ
/url?q=http://www.apva.org/history/jsmith.html&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CB8QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEMx0-702N1edJVXxiS5ILRl651zw
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:iuJ7Uh7IOtgJ:http://www.apva.org/history/jsmith.html%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CCIQIDAB&usg=AFQjCNG_keb3HZAHUteBGMb3k5GTIeVr5w
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:www.apva.org/history/jsmith.html+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CCMQHzAB
/images?q=John+Smith&hl=en&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CCUQsAQ
/url?q=http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/200/269/smith_2.htm&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CCcQ9QEwAg&usg=AFQjCNF3B9TL94enKovOL1hlz-n0A4PXrA
/url?q=http://www.apva.org/history/jsmith.html&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CCkQ9QEwAw&usg=AFQjCNEMx0-702N1edJVXxiS5ILRl651zw
/url?q=http://www.biography.com/people/john-smith-9486928&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CCsQ9QEwBA&usg=AFQjCNEdM50NAIJCmLRDMG_Ruyox4gshPQ
/url?q=http://www.shmoop.com/jamestown/photo-john-smith.html&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CC0Q9QEwBQ&usg=AFQjCNFvEq7Cq3P6WdNIIHpNVVuQLTMhdQ
/url?q=http://www.wpclipart.com/American_History/settlement/John_Smith/Captain_John_Smith.png.html&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CC8Q9QEwBg&usg=AFQjCNGEWlYKoQUhODn-3jypeyaw4urAGw
/url?q=http://www.web-books.com/Classics/ON/B1/B1583/07MB1583.html&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CDEQ9QEwBw&usg=AFQjCNGSF2DNQHhwDTHz4ogVcLVhM5TiDQ
/url?q=http://www.biography.com/people/john-smith-9486928&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CDMQFjAI&usg=AFQjCNEdM50NAIJCmLRDMG_Ruyox4gshPQ
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:IJvKbJ_a540J:http://www.biography.com/people/john-smith-9486928%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CDYQIDAI&usg=AFQjCNHnW1ezRcv8sn_Jk3GBvECp-QOCTg
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:www.biography.com/people/john-smith-9486928+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CDcQHzAI
/url?q=http://johnsmithjohnsmith.com/&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CDkQFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNH9a_jF2woyDESMRrLneIIbbTeS4g
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:_KyTfWhQuFEJ:http://johnsmithjohnsmith.com/%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CDwQIDAJ&usg=AFQjCNGX37w0NUcEFa0t04-28gLhlMVfdA
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:johnsmithjohnsmith.com/+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CD0QHzAJ
/url?q=http://www.johnsmith.co.uk/&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CD8QFjAK&usg=AFQjCNHEhG7WRm1dP5c_0xqqH0P0U-9jUA
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:jPrP5TbGXhYJ:http://www.johnsmith.co.uk/%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEIQIDAK&usg=AFQjCNFe-QSMSKMs8Z6mSu-oLraaeKYAug
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:www.johnsmith.co.uk/+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEMQHzAK
/url?q=http://www.johnsmith.co.uk/uel&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEUQ0gIoADAK&usg=AFQjCNEk2GkTaQvtpqaaYdztlWV7iVs0Jg
/url?q=http://www.johnsmith.co.uk/bedfordshire&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEYQ0gIoATAK&usg=AFQjCNFcOIItpAW46XRn1BwGvuG7mertRA
/url?q=http://www.johnsmith.co.uk/aru&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEcQ0gIoAjAK&usg=AFQjCNFq68oEVG7KAAu-Mbd0ScBFOMF4MA
/url?q=http://www.history.com/topics/john-smith&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEkQFjAL&usg=AFQjCNGytp4P2oI3szUVSzJbJ1YdOWDldw
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:5hQtC90uVmYJ:http://www.history.com/topics/john-smith%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CEwQIDAL&usg=AFQjCNERGtQrhvZLOovq8W-Mp8AXeT_W1g
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:www.history.com/topics/john-smith+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CE0QHzAL
/url?q=http://johnsmithmusic.com/&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CE8QFjAM&usg=AFQjCNFlpAC8HDml6r5DpmAo4VviZ_GeMw
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:-T7dO31PjlkJ:http://johnsmithmusic.com/%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CFIQIDAM&usg=AFQjCNFFeePBNGGMWPaVS9j4_niZpMVyxA
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:johnsmithmusic.com/+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CFMQHzAM
/url?q=http://www.nps.gov/jame/historyculture/life-of-john-smith.htm&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CFUQFjAN&usg=AFQjCNHPmqp05pAUp2yk1R9aKPqohTmWpQ
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:Q_nfCPRpnwQJ:http://www.nps.gov/jame/historyculture/life-of-john-smith.htm%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CFgQIDAN&usg=AFQjCNHad3eFxSDuthM23n4FcusD5rY1uw
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:www.nps.gov/jame/historyculture/life-of-john-smith.htm+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CFkQHzAN
/url?q=http://www.enchantedlearning.com/explorers/page/s/smith.shtml&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CFsQFjAO&usg=AFQjCNEWo4pji9pBq89XmlprWg2okGHl5g
/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:zs0buZvw9N8J:http://www.enchantedlearning.com/explorers/page/s/smith.shtml%252BJohn%2BSmith%26hl%3Den%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CF4QIDAO&usg=AFQjCNEu0cbayJymDVJ4IfbRc_NtrEtaPA
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=related:www.enchantedlearning.com/explorers/page/s/smith.shtml+John+Smith&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CF8QHzAO
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+texture+pack&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGIQ1QIoAA
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+and+pocahontas&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGMQ1QIoAQ
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+actor&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGQQ1QIoAg
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+realty&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGUQ1QIoAw
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+doctor+who&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGYQ1QIoBA
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=captain+john+smith&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGcQ1QIoBQ
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+wrestler&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGgQ1QIoBg
/search?ie=UTF-8&q=john+smith+wrestling&revid=1367094011&sa=X&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&ved=0CGkQ1QIoBw
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=10&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=20&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=30&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=40&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=50&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=60&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=70&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=80&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=90&sa=N
/search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp&ei=9UuFVLvZJ5KLuASVi4KABQ&start=10&sa=N
/advanced_search?q=John+Smith&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsp
/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=134479&hl=en
/tools/feedback/survey/html?productId=196&query=John+Smith&hl=en
/
/intl/en/ads
/services
/intl/en/policies/
/intl/en/about.html
array(0) { }
```

Comment: just check your `$matches` inside the loop and check if it yielded matches

Comment: `$matches` is overriden each time. You should create an array where you **append** the content of each item each time. Otherwise a failure always returns in an empty set and it is likely the last url's, (that are google's page buttons), will empty `$matches`.

Comment: what are the 2 strings, you want the text between the strings. starting and ending ?

Comment: Scrapeing google will get you in trouble

Comment: @Dagon: As far as I known, there is no way to legally enforce some "non scraping" policy. After all you don't sign any contract by visiting a website. And furthermore, one can argue he/she can visit the webpage him/herself and analyze the received source code. It's only when you hit the site multiple times per second, it looks more like a DoS attack. But some websites like *Google Search* will indeed throttle bandwidth by users that look like robots.

Comment: @CommuSoft well google actively detects and sues scrappers, just be careful out there kids :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, is that each time you attempt to match an element, `$matches` is a new array.

A possible solution:

```
$result = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    preg_match_all("/url\?q=(.*?)&sa=U&ei=/", $element->href, $matches); //try to match
    if(array_key_exists(1,$matches) && $matches[1] != "") { //if we found a match
        $result[] = $matches[1]; //push it to $results
    }
}
print_r($result);//print result
```

Another way is of course to try to find some kind of markers in the generated HTML page. You can do this for instance by converting the HTML document to XML and then analyze it. The problem with this approach is however that now and then, *Google* can modify it's page layout and thus you will need to rewrite your algorithm.

Comment: I tried printing out the array at each iteration,

preg_match("/url\?q=(.*?)&sa=U&ei=/", $element->href, $match); 
 print_r($match);  
echo  $element->href.'<br/>';

but still returns an empty array. Im trying to find the URL in between the strings "/url?q=" and "&sa=U&ei="

Comment: Well I copied the list of urls in your example and it returned an array of all "/url?q=..." urls...

Comment: That's why i'm asking because by testing the regex itself, it returns the results I want, it just doesn't do so within the crawler code :(

Comment: Well in that case, I guess the crawler code is wrong, and you should provide that code. One should note that *Google* will probably look at the *agent string* and in case a crawler is used, will return an error page. In other words, your crawler should pretend it is firefox, or another browser.